# How can I load multiple tabs in one different window with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Let's say that I have the following links variables:

```
var link1;
var link2;
var link3;
```

And I have a button in `window A`.

How can I load these three tabs in a separate `window B` (one window, not three) when the button is pressed, as below:

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){ //this button in window A
  window.open(" ");                 //I don't know what to put here
                                    //but should open links 1,2,3 as tabs in window B
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

> Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new tab instead of a
>   new window. It is a user preference.
>
> CSS3 proposed target-new, but the specification was abandoned.
>
> The **reverse** is not true; by specifying dimensions for the window
>   in the third argument of window.open, you can trigger a new window
>   when the preference is for tabs.